# Microsoft Lifecam VX-2000 doesn't work anymore in Cheese

Tags: webcam, cheese

I got have two Lifecam VX-2000's and they don't work in cheese anymore.
I don't know if it's a problem with a missing package, or a package I installed.
Here is the output.

```
(cheese:11122): Clutter-WARNING **: No listener with the specified listener id 29

(cheese:11122): Clutter-WARNING **: No listener with the specified listener id 30

(cheese:11122): Clutter-WARNING **: No listener with the specified listener id 31

(cheese:11122): Clutter-WARNING **: No listener with the specified listener id 32

(cheese:11122): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_remove_internal: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(cheese:11122): Clutter-WARNING **: Not able to remove listener with id 1

(cheese:11122): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_size: assertion `hash_table != NULL'      failed
totem-video-thumbnailer: 'file:///home/myusername/Videos/Webcam/2012-09-20-     191530.webm' isn't thumbnailable
Reason: Media contains no supported video streams.

** (cheese:11122): WARNING **: could not generate thumbnail for       /home/myusername/Videos/Webcam/2012-09-20-191530.webm (video/webm)
```

Notice the:
    Reason: Media contains no supported video streams.

When I try to record a video it just makes a 13.2KB WEBM file with nothing.
When I take a picture it works.
Edit: I've been thinking that the problem started after installing the MediUbuntu repository on my system.

Comment: Do you have another video source? another webcam, tvtuner, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

cheese has bugs

[Install Guvcview (GTK+ UVC Viewer) to Ubuntu 12.04 via ppa](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/18693-install-guvcview-gtk-uvc-viewer-to-ubuntu-1204-via-ppa-)

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/18693-install-guvcview-gtk-uvc-viewer-to-ubuntu-1204-via-ppa-

**Guvcview** aims at providing a simple GTK interface for capturing and viewing video from devices supported by the linux UVC driver, although it should also work with any v4l2 compatible device.

**Install Guvcview to Ubuntu 12.04 via ppa**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pj-assis/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install guvcview
```